# Oracle - Combining fields and search - performance

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a query which ends like this (*I am doing this from java*):

```
WHERE
    c.area_code = ?
AND
    c.cons_no = ?
AND
    c.cat_code = ?
```

Which can be done this way also (*I will be getting below format from user*)

```
WHERE
     c.area_code||'-'||c.cons_no||'-'||c.cat_code=?
```

I read some where that handing over formatting to database will impact performance. That's why I used the first query. Which is the best way of doing this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just bizarre.

The second approach will force a full table scan, and every row of your table to be constructed into the concatenated form for testing against your match string.   It will also break if any of those values is a NULL.   It will also make it impossible to utilize any index that might exist on the three fields you're testing for.

The first way is better.

Comment: The second one might also be subject to "dash injection" if there was a dash in some of the database values.

Answer (score 1):

As second approach is based on String concatenation operations, it will not use the index if it is present on any of the columns. Hence, first approach is better.

Also, if area code does not match then, there is no need to check cons_no and cat_code which is incorporated in first approach.